# Webkit bug for elements displayed inline with jQuery after being hidden

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, inline

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/filter/

As you type in the text box the results are filtered by being hidden and shown by jQuery. Firefox is fine but Chrome and Safari have a weird bug. When elements are shown again, inspecting the elements in the browser tells me their displayed inline but they behave like a block level elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a float to your list items:

```
.list li {
    float:left;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.zone {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```